# Convert dataurlencoded curl command to powershell alterntive {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type"}

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I need help with converting data-urlencoded curl command to powershell
Any help would be highly appreciated

```
curl --location --request POST https://anypoint.muloft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token --header 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=44b1d81330084afbb39c74' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=c38042cda4FD6af9fc18' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I tried this but i am getting

```
     $contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   PS C:\Users\mation> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://anypoint.muloft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token") -ContentType $contentType -Method Post -Body { client_id="44b1d81330039c74" ;client_secret = "c38042cE3D6af9fc18" ; grant_type= "authorization_code" }


   Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type"}
   At line:1 char:1
    + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/v ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is what worked for me

$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://anypoint.muloft.com/accounts/api/v2/oauth2/token"

$ClientId = "44b1d8bb39c74"

$ClientSecret = "c380f9fc18"

$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret"

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'